# In Scala returning a value from a for loop block

Tags: scala, for-loop, functional-programming, scala-collections

In the book "Scala for the impatient", it says on page 16

> In Scala, a { } block contains a sequence of expressions, and the
>   result is also an expression. The value of the block is the value of
>   the last expression.

OK, then let's create a block and let the last value of the block be assigned:

```
scala> val evens = for (elem <- 1 to 10 if elem%2==0) {
     |   elem
     | }
val evens: Unit = ()
```

I would have expected that `evens` is at least the last value of the sequence (i.e. `10`). But why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unit` is the exception to the rule stated in your book. `Unit` basically says "ignore whatever type the block would have returned because I only intended to execute the block for the side effects." Otherwise, in order to get it to typecheck, you'd have to add a unit value to the end of any block that was supposed to return `Unit`:

```scala
val evens = for (elem <- 1 to 10 if elem%2==0) {
  elem
  ()
}
```

This throwing away of type information is one reason people tend to avoid imperative for loops and similar in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `yield` the value, then it's a for expression:

```
val evens = for (elem <- 1 to 10 if elem % 2 == 0) yield elem
```

Without that it's just a statement (does not return anything) and is translated to `foreach`.

P.S.: Of course this will return a collection of all the elements that fulfill the predicate and not the last one.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt just run it through the typechecker to peek under the hood

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e 'val evens = for (elem <- 1 to 10 if elem%2==0) { elem }'
```

reveals

```
val evens: Unit = 
  scala.Predef
    .intWrapper(1)
    .to(10)
    .withFilter(((elem: Int) => elem.%(2).==(0)))
    .foreach[Int](((elem: Int) => elem))
```

where we see `foreach` to be the last step in the chain, and its signature is

```
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit
```

where we see it returns `Unit`. You can even do this straight from within the REPL by executing the following command

```
scala> :settings -Xprint:typer
```

and now you will get real-time desugaring of Scala expressions at the same time they are interpreted. You can even take it a step further and get at the JVM bytecode itself

```
scala> :javap -
```

For-comprehensions are some of the most prevalent syntactic sugar in Scala so I would suggest to drill them as much as possible by perhaps trying to write them at the same time in both their suggared and desugared from until it clicks: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

Comment: Nice explanation !